# How to replace numeric values with strings in DataFrame column based on the values of original numbers Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a DataFrame column with numeric values eg.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'my_col':[1,0,1,0,4,5,8,10,12]})
```

In the column *my_col* I want to replace all values based on a set of conditions:

- '1 or less' if smaller than or equal to 1
- '2 to 10' if larger than 1
  and less than 10
- 'more than 10' if larger than 10

I've tried:

```
df.loc[(type(df['my_col']) != str) & (df['my_col'] < 2), 'my_col'] = '1 or less'
df.loc[(type(df['my_col']) != str) & (df['my_col'] > 1) & (df['my_col'] <= 10),'my_col'] = '2 to 10'
df.loc[(type(df['my_col']) != str) & (df['my_col'] > 10), 'my_col'] = 'more than 10'
```

I get the following error:
*TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'*

It seems the first row executes fine but after that the column contains mix of numeric and str values

So I've tried getting around this by attempting to first filter out str values before I commence with the second line of code, using:

```
df.loc[type(df['my_col']) != str]
```

but this give error: *'boolean label can not be used without a boolean index'*

So I've even tried this kind of thing:

```
df[df['my_col'].apply(lambda x: not isinstance(x, str))].loc[(df['my_col'] > 1) & (df['my_col'] <= 10),'my_col'] = '2 to 10'
```

but then if I return my df, the values were not assigned.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.cut`.

```
pd.cut(df['my_col'], bins=[float('-inf'), 1, 10, float('inf')], labels=['1 or less', '2 to 10', 'more than 10'])
```

This assumes you are dealing with integers only, e.g. no `1.5` that would be labeled as `'2 to 10'`.

Comment: First time I see the use of labels, definitely something I will use. I suggest using np.NINF and np.INF instead of float('-inf') btw.

Comment: @Learningisamess there is no np.INF